# Restrict users to edit not owned products

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I tried to register rule with the following condition

```
[('create_uid','in',[user.id])]
```

applying to product object.
But I don't get what I need.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Check that the model you are trying to write is the same with the rule Objet.